# SQLite Triggers: Only have a trigger take an action when a certain field is NOT included in the query?

Tags: sqlite, triggers, conditional-statements

As is common, I've got a trigger that updates a date_last_modified field in one of my tables.  The issue I've run into is sometimes I need to manually adjust the timestamp in that date_last_modified field.  When I do, though, the trigger fires and sets it right back to now().

Here is my trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Preference_on_update After UPDATE ON Preference for each row 
begin 
    update Preference set date_last_modified = datetime('now') 
    where rowid = old.rowid; 
end
```

What I'd like to do is ONLY have this trigger fire when the update does not already include a value for the date_last_modified field.  If the update statement included date_last_modified, the trigger should not adjust anything.

I've looked through the docs and syntax for triggers for SQLite, and see there is a "WHEN" clause, but none of my incantations of it so far have been fruitful.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

Triggers can be restricted to a specific set of columns:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Preference_on_update
AFTER UPDATE OF ID, Name, Value, Description ON Preference
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    ...
```

However, this does not help when the date is changed together with any of these other columns.

A better idea is to check whether the date value was actually changed, i.e., whether the old and new values are different.
(`<>` is always false when NULL values are involved, so it's better to use `IS NOT NULL` here.)

```
CREATE TRIGGER Preference_on_update
AFTER UPDATE ON Preference
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN OLD.date_last_modified IS NOT NEW.date_last_modified
BEGIN
    ...
```

Comment: Awesome!  This looks to be the way to go for this particular problem.  I'll give it a whirl and make noise here if there are any issues.

Comment: Hmm... Your example seems to always produce a syntax error on the "FOR EACH ROW" line.  Seems the triggers syntax does not like your IS NOT comparison.

But, in looking at the syntax docs here: https://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#expr it appears your syntax should be valid.  

Stumped.

Comment: `FOR EACH ROW` must come before `WHEN`.